# Process Builder Deployment Error

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, process

While deploying one process builder from One Sandbox to another sandbox I'm getting below error:

> name(Action Call) - We can't find an action with the name and action type that you specified.

It is giving that particular name but I'm not able to find this particular action in my sandbox.

Comment: apex invocable action?

Comment: not it is invoked from process builder

Answer (score 0):

We've had this happen to us a lot.  Just clone the process builder, be sure the flow is active, activate your process builder.  That normally clears up that error.